# How to send image and text inside richtextbox as mail body in windows form

Tags: .net, winforms

How to send image and text inside richtextbox as mail body in windows form . What i have done now is , first i converted the richtextbox.rtf to html and pass the html data to mail body. But what is happening is the images in the html code is showing as wmf format and is not showing in receiving side. What to do now.?

Answer (score 1):

i have a solution for your post, try this.
Please find below sample its directly sent Richtexbox value to email body

```
public bool Send_Mail(string MessageBody, string Link)

{

try

{

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace NS = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder objFolder = NS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem objMail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)objFolder.Items.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem); 

//objMail.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText;

objMail.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

objMail.Body = rtxtExtMessage.RichTextBox.Text +"\n\nTo continue discussion click the following link: " + Link;

objMail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;

objMail.To = txtTo.Text;

objMail.CC = txtCc.Text;

objMail.Send();

return true;

}

catch

{

return false;

}
```

}

if you need more information please find below url
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/90f79bfa-76af-4813-9741-08ffa6a36ae9/sending-the-formatted-text-as-an-email-using-c

Comment: But i dont want to send it via outlook , i am creating a mail sending application in windows form